# windows xp , 7 service interactive with each logged in user but ran as admin / service

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, java, windows-services

I am a Java developer and what this for my application. This is more of a windows issue than of Java.

It has been one week x 8 hours a day or more since I am only at this issue, listening to other people's advice, searching, reading articles, similar posts and experimenting.

Couldn't find a proper solution. But I am still sure there is a trick work around that I failed to grasp.

1. I want to run a `GUI app` when `any user logs in.`
2. I want to `run` that app `as administrator or system service`(Admin password is available) (but `separate instance for each user` so it can interact with each user separately?)
3. I `do not want` the `user to be able to delete the app file or close / stop that app while its running`. Only admins can terminate the app.

Task `scheduler` or `services` dont let the app run as admin/system on normal desktops of each normal users **`as "interactive"`** application to desktop.
Services are normally none interactive non guis unlless made interactive.

Please only reply if you know precisely the exact "**working solution**" in the exact way stated. take the example of notepade.exe

---

side notes:

I heard VirtualBox is open source and has an admin level service with multiple user level GUI instances. So I guess it is attainable

---

very thankful for responders and upvoters.
downvoters (if any). state reason to downvote so I can improve

Comment: This is actually a stackoverflow.com question

Comment: @medigeek actually the stack users said something similar. see the first comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317139/windows-xp-7-service-interactive-with-each-logged-in-user-but-ran-as-admin-s

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea from the Linux world:

In Linux, the general idea is to use 2 programs:

- one "master service" (as administrator, in the background). Note: A service in linux is called a daemon
- one or more "client service" that are run on user level

The "master service" will have administrative privileges and will accept and process and respond to commands sent from "client service".

The "client service" will send commands according to a friendly GUI.

The two interact using "DBus", a messaging system. Windows Sockets is the equivalent I think in Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482681/d-bus-equivalent-for-windows

Comment: need for windows

Comment: How about [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776457/java-client-server-application-with-sockets) and.. [this](http://developeriq.in/articles/2012/may/01/transforming-java-programs-into-windows-services-u/) (see about apache commons for the last one).

Comment: all that is non-interactive service

Comment: What do you mean by _non-interactive_? :) The first example shows a server program listening to a socket port and printing a text string that was sent from a client service. Receive and respond -- that is interactivity, isn't it?

Comment: @medlgeek  at the event of a user log in, the java service server app will lauch the app? if it does, the app will be ran as the server user, that is SYSTEM and it will again not be GUI based or interactive

Comment: If you make the system service, you can make a GUI window that interacts through socket ports with the service. That's the safest and best solution I can think of.

Comment: By "interactive" he means the setting on services to "interact with the desktop", i.e. can display & take input from a user, as detailed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502(v=vs.85).aspx & shown at http://www.tec-it.com/pics/TWedge/twedge2-services-windows.jpg

Comment: the top most problem i am facing is that how to start the actuall frontend application so that the user cant stop it and it also interacts with his desktop